# Comparing two dates for past or not in rails 3.1 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my ruby(1.9.3) on rails (3.1) app I'm trying to set some conditional behavior with respect to tasks and deadlines. Specifically the coloring of a progress bar.

```
Tasks belongs_to list
List has_many tasks
```

I'm essentialy trying to see if the last `task.planned_for` date in `@list.tasks` is past `@list.deadline.`

Both `list.deadline` and `task.planned_for` are :date types.

So in my view I'm looking for something like:

```
- if @last_task.planned_for > @list.deadline
```

Where

```
@tasks = @list.tasks.todo
@last_task = @tasks.last
```

Any ideas on how to best do this. This (obviously) isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `@tasks.last` doesn't grab the latest one, it grabs the last one in the database, not in any particular order.   You probably want to get it with

```
@last_task = @list.tasks.order('planned_for DESC').first`
```

(by ordering it descending, the first date is latest)

Comment: I'm getting this error: `undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass`